# Window Terminal Server 2003 - unique user directories on server

Tags: windows-server-2003

We have an older PC network application that was written that requires that each user have their own unique `C:\prog_dir\`.  On networked PCs this is not a problem with with Terminal Server, all our RDP connections see the same `C:\prog_dir`.  Is there a way to create a unique `C:\prog_dir\` for each RDP user?

Comment: You probably already thought of this, but to make sure: Is the "C:\prog_dir" path hard coded? Or can you set it via a configuration file? (preferably a configuration file which allows %userdir%).

Answer (score 0):

Look into either assigning policies or apply a login.bat/vbs for your users.  It is possible to create login scripts for various users that is entirely variable based so as to support future users.